# Можно ли отправлять сообщения из своей программы на whats app

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

Здравствуйте.Появилась нужда в такой программе на андроид из которой можно отправлять сообщения на whatsApp.Есть ли на это api и вообще можно ли такое сделать?

Comment: Читаем faq https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012 , гуглим "WhatsApp Android Api"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, можно, но для этого не нужен API, достаточно использовать стандартный механизм `Intent`, приблизительно так:

```
PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
String text = "Текст сообщения";
//задаем получателя
String telNumber="+7916****123";
intent.putExtra("jid", telNumber+"@s.whatsapp.net");
PackageInfo info=pm.getPackageInfo("com.whatsapp", PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
//проверяем есть ли Whatsapp (может выкинуть Exception если нет whatsapp)
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
```

Более подробно расписано в [FAQ Whatsapp](https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/28000012)

Comment: можно ли сделать так чтобы это сообщение автоматом уходила на какую то группу..Чтобы и другие люди могли читать? тут я так понял отправка только для своего установленного whatsApp?

Comment: обновил ответ с получателем